# app.facebook.com/app_name/ - to redirect to a external url after clicking “go to app”

Tags: facebook, facebook-application, facebook-graph

I know there is a way to redirect the page using javascript in the iframe of the canvas application to an external url.But is there any other way so that user directly gets redirected to the external url as soon as they authorizes the application.

i know it is possible because a famous app klout in Facebook does it.
http://apps.facebook.com/klout__/

redirects to

http://klout.com/ automatically as soon as the user

Remember i got an invitation request from my Facebook friend.when i clicked the invitation notification and when i authorized the application it redirected to a external url.Any idea how this has been done? And i think this wont be encouraged in Facebook policies either?

Comment: The Offical facebook developer support channel is stackoverflow, you might get on better there...